# how to get current salesforce instance in script of a VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have below code

```
    <apex:page>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Test(){
        var url = 'https://ap1.salesforce.com/00O900000070URt';
        window.parent.location.replace(url);
    }
</script>
<apex:outputLink onclick="Test();">
    <analytics:reportChart reportId="00O900000070URt"></analytics:reportChart>
</apex:outputLink>
</apex:page>
```

If you can observe the var url is hard coded with current instance which will fail if we move this code to prod or any other environment.

please advice how to handle this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. you need to get the first part below in apex controller and use a controller variable in javascript to access the value.

Documentation for URL class [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_url.htm)

`URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()`/**addtheidthat you want to**

In Apex class you will get the URL and Id you want to append,

```
    public String reportsURL{get; set; } 
    reportsURL = 'URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()'+Idoftherecord; 
//set this in the constructor of apex class
```

In javascript just access and get the variable

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Test(){
        var url = '{!JSENCODE(reportsURL)}';//variable you created in apex controller
        window.parent.location.replace(url);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please show me in example piece of code

Comment: @vara, check it out now

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable in your Visualforce controller since [Salesforce will be removing the instance name from the address in the future](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_vf_instance_names_removed.htm) (16 Mar 2019).

Assign to said variable the instance the field `InstanceName` retrieved from the `Organization` object:

```
Organization orgInfo = [SELECT Id, InstanceName FROM Organization];
String thisInstancesName = orgInfo.InstanceName;
```

On the Visualforce page this would look like:

```
...
var url = 'https://{!thisInstancesName}.salesforce.com/00O900000070URt';
...
```